# Why does the reqwest HTTP library return binary data instead of a text body?

Tags: http, rust, reqwest

I am trying to perform a HTTP GET request with reqwest and print the response body to STDOUT. This works for most websites, but it returns weird binary output for amazon.com:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    run().await;
}

async fn run() {
    let url = "https://www.amazon.com/PNY-GeForce-Gaming-Overclocked-Graphics/dp/B07GJ7TV8L/";
    let resp = reqwest::get(url).await.unwrap();
    let text = resp.text().await.unwrap();
    println!("{}", text);
}
```

Why would `resp.text().await.unwrap()` return binary data and how can I obtain normal HTTP body from it?

curl returns the HTML I expected:

```
curl https://www.amazon.com/PNY-GeForce-Gaming-Overclocked-Graphics/dp/B07GJ7TV8L/
```

Comment: You're right. but in this particular case other HTTP clients return text (e.g curl). I'll update the question.

Comment: "UPDATE: curl returns normal HTML as expected:" not for me. you probably have a client that auto decompress the body or that ask to the server to not send compressed file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do `curl https://www.amazon.com/PNY-GeForce-Gaming-Overclocked-Graphics/dp/B07GJ7TV8L/ - I` you will see:

```
server: Server
content-type: text/html
content-length: 2148
content-encoding: gzip
x-amz-rid: 2T9PBCY66S79SMC424V2
vary: Accept-Encoding
akamai-cache-status: Miss
date: Sat, 29 Feb 2020 22:23:54 GMT
```

`content-encoding: gzip` it's quite obvious what you need to do. Checkout [`gzip`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.3/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html#method.gzip) from reqwest. `gzip` is a [optional features](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.3/reqwest/index.html#optional-features), see [cargo doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section), for reqwest you can write `reqwest = { version = "0.10.3", features = ["gzip"] }` in your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it previously, but it did not work out... I just figured out, that `gzip` is a crate feature that needs to be explicitly enabled.

The following now works for me:

reqwest = { version = "=0.10.3", features = [ "gzip"] }

Comment: @SergeyPotapov Good catch, BTW look like sometime amazon return an uncompressed file randomly.

Comment: How is it obvious? Having to select a specific feature for the library doesn't seem like good library design. 99% of users would want gzip enabled by default.